# Using user input to change a property

Tags: c#

I have a simple class with 2 properties:

```
    class Circle {
protected int x = 0 {get; set;}
protected int y = 0 {get; set;} 
}
```

I have another class where the user can write which property he wants to change.

```
string selectProperty = Input.ReadString("Write which property to you want to change");
```

In the same class I have a circle object, and I just want to change the value of a property according to his selection, to 5.

```
circle.selectProperty = 5;
```

This is just small example, I want to know the main idea, so 2 small "if"s won't help...
Thank you!

Comment: Try something like this: `circle.GetType().GetProperty(selectProperty).SetValue(circle, 5)`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Fabjan That's not working... any idea why?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I'm trying to change a specific property that the user chose. Like an edit page.

Comment: @user7399016 One possible reason is that property's access modifier is `protected`, you can change it to `public` or use Bindingflags overload in `GetProperty` method.

Comment: @Fabjan That's working! I changed it to public. Can you explain me the second way, with Bindingflags? What's that? Because I need this property protected... Thanks again!

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zy0d4103%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you can use a second parameter in GetProperty:
circle.GetType().GetProperty(selectedProperty, BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | 
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).setValue(circle, 5);

Comment: @user7399016 By default `GetProperty()` method can only find public properties however this can be changed by passing another parameter of type: BindingFlags enumeration , this parameter allows method to access private properties. You can read more here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use reflection.

```
Circle circle = new Circle();
string selectProperty = Input.ReadString("Write which property to you want to change");
string selectedValue = Input.ReadString("Write which value should be written");
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = circle.GetType().GetProperty(selectedProperty);
propertyInfo.SetValue(circle, Convert.ChangeType(selectedValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

That should give you an idea.

Comment: What's that PropertyInfo thing?

Comment: A class of the Reflection namespace which provides functionality to dynamically access properties of classes (in your case you are accessing properties by their name). Have a look at a .NET reflection tutorial. Basically you are able to access compiled objects at runtime which gives you great possibilities.